# JSF page autocalls a method twice

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ejb

I've got a strange problem with JSF.

I've got a PrimeFaces GraphicImage that calls a method to get the Image.

Now, I've written this method to be used just by this component, so I expect it to be called just once, but here's the surprise :
in the same page, this method is called two times and with different parameters!

```
<pou:graphicImage rendered="true" height="150" style="border: 1px dotted; margin-left: 150px;" value="#{userDataBean.getAvatar()}" width="150"/>

public StreamedContent getImage(Utente u) throws IOException {
    File avatar = new File(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRealPath("/resources/images/no_avatar.png"));
    if (u.getFoto() == null) {
        return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(Files.readAllBytes(avatar.toPath())), "image/jpeg");
    }
    return new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(u.getFoto()), "image/jpeg");
}

public StreamedContent getImage() throws IOException {
    return getImage(utente);
}
```

So, getImage(Utente u) is a generic method that works without problems.

`utente` in `getImage()` is a user got from `#{request.getParameter('user')}`

Now, I use this method to show an avatr in user's profile.

The problem is that, when I open the profile page, `getImage()` is called two times :
the first time, the value is correct and it loads the avatar of the user.
But it gets called a second time, and this time `utente` takes the value of `#{loginBean.utente}`, that's the logged in user, causing this line to show the avatar of the logged user instead of the one of the user that we want to show.

So here's the question :
how can I stop this method from being called once, even if I wrote it just ONE time?

I don't understand what's happening :|

Comment: your problem is not reproduceable with your provided code